# How can I see through the mesh without going into wireframe mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, wireframe

[image]

Constantly switching between wireframe mode and solid view mode (if that's the right term for it) is somewhat of a pain, but I remember seeing a tutorial where someone had the mesh transparent while the wireframe in edit mode was still visible. So how do I make the mesh transparent in edit mode?

Comment: Are you looking for X-Ray mode? `Alt+X` or the button just left to the wireframe mode button.

Comment: @taiyo You mean Alt Z

Comment: As @moonboots says, it's Alt-Z to toggle x-ray mode. but you can also toggle between wireframe and solid mode with Shift-Z.  Z on its own brings up a pie menu where you have all the options and, once you've got the technique, you can just flick the mouse in the direction of the option you want  to switch modes.

Comment: @moonboots no i mean Alt+X (Industry Compatible), yours is Alt+Z (Blender). To avoid confusion for others: changeable under _Edit > Preferences... > Keymap_

Comment: @taiyo That is not helpful for regular Blender users who expect the default keymap!

Comment: @JohnEason ok, got it. Thats why i added the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Click this. It will turn on x-ray mode.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I must've misunderstood

Comment: @JohnEason where do you read that? OP says he is switching between _Wireframe_ and _Solid_ viewport mode and is looking for that transparent option, which is most likely X-Ray on/off. I think Pineapple's answer is right.

Comment: @taiyo Ah. Ok. My bad. I'll delete that comment.

Comment: Ok but the problem with the X-ray mode is that it's either 100% transparent or nothing. I tried adjusting it even to 0.999, but it's only giving those 2 options.